# AJAX Request and Simple Request

Tags: ajax, http-protocols

Should a ajax Request obey the rule:
one request , one response;
What is the essential differences between ajax request and simple request
 for HTTP Protocol?

Answer (score 0):

### **Simple Answer:** Yes

### Complex Answer

Ajax is build on the concept of making **a** request and receiving **a** response.  Can use any of the **CRUD** operations (`GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`)

An HTTP request is different because it is expecting a **HTTP** response as opposed to a **JSON** or **XML** response.  Also it only uses the `GET` protocol of HTTP.

You can use a subscription protocol (**XMPP**) or something like **SignalR**.  These are built to make a request that then receives multiple `responses` and might send more `requests`.